# While inserting new record into database, it is updating old record in grid view

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview

Grid view updating old record, when i'm trying to add new record.

In grid view I have a edit option. If I click on edit, the particular row is going to edit screen and filling textboxes and updating as expected. When clicking on add new record button in grid view, it is going to add screen with empty textboxes as expected, but if I add a new record, it is updating the previous record which was edited.

```
protected void GV_PRIOR_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    int pid = Convert.ToInt32(GV_PRIOR.DataKeys[e.NewSelectedIndex].Value);
    DataTable dt = bll.editprior(pid);
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        HiddenField1.Value = dr["P_ID"].ToString();
        tb_prioname.Text = dr["P_NAME"].ToString();
        chk_actprior.Checked = dr["P_ACTIVE"].ToString() == "Y";
    }
    btn_savprior.Text = "UPDATE";                
}

protected void btn_savprior_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HiddenField1.Value == "")
    {
        bll.savprior(0, tb_prioname.Text, Convert.ToBoolean(chk_actprior.Checked));
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Priority Saved Successfully')</script>");

    }
    else
    {
        bll.savprior(Convert.ToInt16(HiddenField1.Value), tb_prioname.Text, Convert.ToBoolean(chk_actprior.Checked));
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Priority Updated Successfully')</script>");
    }
    bindgrid();              
}
```

If I click on the add new record button, after filling textboxes it should add a new record, but it is updating the old record which was edited just before adding new record.

```
Stored Procedure:

    ALTER PROC [dbo].[SAVEPRIOR]
  @P_ID int,
  @P_NAME varchar(20),
  @P_ACTIVE char(1)
  AS
  BEGIN
  IF(@P_ID=0)     
  BEGIN
  INSERT INTO PRIORITY(P_NAME) VALUES (@P_NAME)
  END   
  ELSE  
  BEGIN
  UPDATE PRIORITY SET P_NAME=@P_NAME,P_ACTIVE=@P_ACTIVE WHERE P_ID=@P_ID
  END
  END

DAL:

public void savePRIOR(int id, string priorname, bool actv )
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SAVEPRIOR", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P_ID", id);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P_NAME", priorname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P_ACTIVE", (actv) ? "Y" : "N");            
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }

BAL:

 public void savprior(int id, string priorname, bool actv )
    {
        dll.savePRIOR(id, priorname, actv);
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible, that the `bll` object stores the id of the record you edit somewhere and uses this to update a record instead of creating one?

Comment: If i edit record and update it, it is correctly updating and coming back to gridview and highlighting that edited record but now if i try to add new record,it is updating the highlighted record.

Comment: Can you please verfiy, if after saving a record `GV_PRIOR_SelectedIndexChanging` is called? Or any other method that would set `HiddenField1.Value = dr["P_ID"].ToString();` or something like this. I'm guessing this is causing your add record, to take that Id and update it

Answer (score -1):

Try to clear the  HiddenField1.Value="";
before bindgrid();

Comment: Hey thank u abhijit..it worked after clearing hiddenfield value Thank u so much guys